# Execution failed for ':app:ndkBuild'. Process 'command ndk-build.cmd' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, opencv, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have been stuck on this problem for 2 days and have tried out all possible solutions given on stackoverflow. Below is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = []
    sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.anannyauberoi.testingcam"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        moduleName "app"
        cFlags "-std=c++11 -fexceptions"
        ldLibs "log"
        stl "gnustl_shared"
        abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = []
    res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
    jniLibs.srcDirs=['src/main/libs']
} }
//sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = []
// disable automatic ndk-build call, which ignore our Android.mk

task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    commandLine "C:/Users/Anannya-Uberoi/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd",
            'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
            'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
            'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
            'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}

tasks.all { task ->
    if (task.name.startsWith('compile') && task.name.endsWith('Ndk')) {
        task.enabled = false
    }
}

// call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory

}
    //Modify the below set of code to the ndk-build.cmd location in your computer.

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary249')
}
```

I have already tried all possible solutions- deleting the obj folder in the build folder, trying to avoid automatic Android.mk call by setting the sourceSets.main, trying to avoid the compileDebugNdk task from getting called. I also do not have any cmake.txt files. I cannot seem to get over the problem.

I have used Android Studio 2.3.2 and 2.1.1 and the problem has persisted in both of them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `"Execution failed for ':app:ndkBuild'. Process 'command ndk-build.cmd' finished with non-zero exit value 2"` is it all? nothing more?

Comment: @pskink The exact error is `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:cleanNative'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Anannya-Uberoi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2`. This is the only error I'm getting.

Comment: run `gradlew` from the command line then - it is located at the top level folder of your project

Comment: Open the Terminal in Android Studio (Alt+F12 in Windows). Then run `cd app/src/main/jni` then run `ndk-build V=1`. This will tell you exactly why the build is failing.

Comment: Or, from the Terminal, you can run from your app's main directory `gradlew --info` or `gradlew --stacktrace` or `gradlew --debug`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the latest Android Studio, 2.3.2 is OK. It has integrated externalNativeBuild in android gradle plugin, so you don't need the tricks with custom gradle task.

I could not actually test the **build.gradle** script below, so please forgive me any typos:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.anannyauberoi.testingcam"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            targets "app"
            cppFlags "-std=c++11 -fexceptions"
            arguments "APP_STL=gnustl_shared"
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { 
  res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
} }

externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path "src/main/jni/Android.mk"
    }
}

    //Modify the below set of code to the ndk-build.cmd location in your computer.

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary249')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I went to:

```
C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd
```

directory and for the `ndk-build.cmd` i press

Right-Click> Edit and change the cmd file from:

```
@echo off
%~dp0\build\ndk-build.cmd %*
```

to

```
@echo off
THAT works for me
```