# How can I merge two Android.mk files when adding a library?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm new with Android so I don't fully understand how to make Android.mk files. 
My project was running fine, following a tutorial online where the Android.mk was provided. But later on I needed to add a missing library and the tutorial for that had another Android.mk, now I'm trying to merge the two together.

**Here is my Android.mk :**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#opencv
OPENCVROOT:= C:\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_example_adrien_ndkopencvtest4_OpencvNativeClass.cpp


LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog

LOCAL_MODULE := MyOpencvLibs


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Here is the Android.mk I need to add :**

```
LOCAL_PATH  := $(call my-dir)
OPENCV_PATH := D:/CODE/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := nonfree
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libnonfree.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES := on
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES  := off
include $(OPENCV_PATH)/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=             \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)               \
    $(OPENCV_PATH)/include

LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=              \
    nonfree_jni.cpp

LOCAL_MODULE := nonfree_demo
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Werror -O3 -ffast-math
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ldl
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += nonfree

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

What I'm interested in in the last Android.mk is the libnonfree.so only, I don't need the cpp file.

**Here is the structure of my project :**

[image]

**EDIT :**

Thanks for your answers. I've done what was suggested and my Android.mk looks like that now :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#opencv
OPENCVROOT:= C:\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_example_adrien_ndkopencvtest4_OpencvNativeClass.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += nonfree
LOCAL_MODULE := MyOpencvLibs
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := nonfree
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libnonfree.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But the problem remains. I've got "Undefined reference" to methods libnonfree.so should add. I assumed the problem was from the Android.mk but maybe it's from elsewhere then.

I've added `System.loadLibrary("nonfree");` to my `MainACtivity` and

```
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT 2 :**

**Here is the error :**

[image]

**Application.mk :**

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-16
```

I didn't know where to set `arguments="V=1"` in my build.gradle

**My build.gradle :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.adrien.ndkopencvtest4"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        //jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
        commandLine "C:/Users/Adrien/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd",
                'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
                'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
                'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
                'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
    }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever-armeabi-v7a:1.0.14'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary2410')

}
```

**EDIT 3 :**

**Results of "ndk-build V=1" :**

```
C:\Users\Adrien\AndroidStudioProjects\NDKOpencvTest4\app\src\main\jni>ndk-build V=1

[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libMyOpencvLibs.so
C:/Users/Adrien/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/llvm/preb
uilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -Wl,-soname,libMyOpencvLibs.so -shared --sysroo
t=C:/Users/Adrien/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../platforms/android-
16/arch-arm C:/Users/Adrien/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKOpencvTest4/app/src/main/obj/l
ocal/armeabi-v7a/objs/MyOpencvLibs/com_example_adrien_ndkopencvtest4_OpencvNativeCl
ass.o C:/Users/Adrien/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-st
l/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a -lgcc C:/Users/Adrien/Andro
idStudioProjects/NDKOpencvTest4/app/src/main/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java.s
o C:/Users/Adrien/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKOpencvTest4/app/src/main/obj/local/armea
bi-v7a/libnonfree.so  -gcc-toolchain C:/Users/Adrien/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-
bundle/build//../toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -no-c
anonical-prefixes -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8  -Wl,--b
uild-id -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--warn-sh
ared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings   -LC:/Users/Adrien/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk
-bundle/build//../platforms/android-16/arch-arm/usr/lib -llog -lc -lm -o C:/Users/A
drien/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKOpencvTest4/app/src/main/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libMy
OpencvLibs.so
C:/Users/Adrien/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKOpencvTest4/app/src/main/jni/com_example_a
drien_ndkopencvtest4_OpencvNativeClass.cpp:214: error: undefined reference to 'cv::
SURF::SURF(double, int, int, bool, bool)'
C:/Users/Adrien/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKOpencvTest4/app/src/main/jni/com_example_a
drien_ndkopencvtest4_OpencvNativeClass.cpp:222: error: undefined reference to 'cv::
SURF::SURF()'
C:/Users/Adrien/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKOpencvTest4/app/src/main/jni/com_example_a
drien_ndkopencvtest4_OpencvNativeClass.cpp:204: error: undefined reference to 'VTT
for cv::SURF'
C:/Users/Adrien/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKOpencvTest4/app/src/main/jni/com_example_a
drien_ndkopencvtest4_OpencvNativeClass.cpp:204: error: undefined reference to 'VTT
for cv::SURF'
C:/Users/Adrien/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKOpencvTest4/app/src/main/jni/com_example_a
C:/Users/Adrien/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKOpencvTest4/app/src/main/jni/com_example_adrien_ndkopencvtest4_OpencvNativeClass.cpp:204: error: undefined
reference to 'VTT for cv::SURF'
C:/Users/Adrien/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKOpencvTest4/app/src/main/jni/com_example_adrien_ndkopencvtest4_OpencvNativeClass.cpp:449: error: undefined
reference to 'cv::SURF::SURF(double, int, int, bool, bool)'
C:/Users/Adrien/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKOpencvTest4/app/src/main/jni/com_example_adrien_ndkopencvtest4_OpencvNativeClass.cpp:457: error: undefined
reference to 'cv::SURF::SURF()'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [C:/Users/Adrien/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKOpencvTest4/app/src/main/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libMyOpencvLibs.so] Error 1
```

**SOLUTION :**

My libnonfree.so file was not correct, I downloaded another one. I also changed my `Application.mk` file to :

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-16
```

Comment: Please show what errors you see. To understand how your **Android.mk** is interpreted, run `ndk-build V=1` from command line (or you can set `arguments="V=1"` in the **build.gradle** file). Note that you should be very careful about the contents of your **Application.mk** file, too. And make sure that your APK only builds **armeabi-v7a**, because you don't have **libnonfree.so** for other ABIs.

Comment: I've edited my answer, thank you for your time.

Comment: You have this `commandLine` string. Add `'V=1'` as one of its arguments.

Comment: Android Studio v. 2.3 has integrated **externalNativeBuild** in android gradle plugin, so you don't need the tricks with custom gradle task. See e.g. this [build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44188168/192373).

Comment: Cool. Does the file `C:/Users/Adrien/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKOpencvTest4/app/src/main/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libnonfree.so` really exist?

Comment: Now open command line and run run `C:\Users\Adrien\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-nm -DC C:/Users/Adrien/AndroidStudioProjects/NDKOpencvTest4/app/src‌​/main/obj/local/arme‌​abi-v7a/libnonfree.s‌​o`. Does the output include **cv::
SURF::SURF** ?

Comment: Yes, it does exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145361/discussion-between-alex-cohn-and-megatron300).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a prebuilt shared library to your project, you don't need a separate **Android.mk**

Let's take your script,

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#opencv
OPENCVROOT:= C:\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_example_adrien_ndkopencvtest4_OpencvNativeClass.cpp


LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog

LOCAL_MODULE := MyOpencvLibs


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and simply add to the bottom the extra module you need:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := nonfree
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libnonfree.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Now the file `C:\Users\Adrien\AndroidStudioProjects\NDKOpencvTest4\app\src\main\jni\libnonfree.so` will be packed into your APK.

If you need this library to link your **libMyOpencvLibs.so** (this means, if your code in **com_example_adrien_ndkopencvtest4_OpencvNativeClass.cpp** uses some functions exported from **libnonfree.so**, you should also refeence it in your module:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#opencv
OPENCVROOT:= C:\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_example_adrien_ndkopencvtest4_OpencvNativeClass.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += nonfree
LOCAL_MODULE := MyOpencvLibs
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := nonfree
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libnonfree.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your android.mk as:

```
LOCAL_PATH  := $(call my-dir)
OPENCV_PATH := D:/CODE/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := nonfree
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libnonfree.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#opencv
OPENCVROOT:= C:\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_example_adrien_ndkopencvtest4_OpencvNativeClass.cpp

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += nonfree

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog

LOCAL_MODULE := MyOpencvLibs

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Here the prebuild library i.e. libnonfree.so is declared in the android.mk, and referenced to it later via

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += nonfree
```

Now to use it you need to load the latest built library in yout MainActivity i.e.

```
System.loadLibrary("MyOpencvLibs");
```

Thats it, now you have merged both the android.mk files into a new module named: MyOpencvLibs

For better understanding you can read my blog : https://androidtutsweb.wordpress.com/2017/04/04/android-mk-for-ndk-build-using-pre-build-libraries/