# Execution failed for task ":app:ndkBuild". >Process 'Command' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Hi guys I am currently following a tutorial on Youtube to create a mobile application using android studio, unfortunately I ran into a few errors and could not solve it myself. The errors are the same for both the .cpp and .h file. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance! :)

This is the error in my gradle build:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.
> Process 'command 'C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-
build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

This is my .h File (Android studio says that there is a typo error for "jint" and missing ";"):

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

/* Header for class com_example_dell_mpdetecthumans_OpencvNativeClass */

#ifndef _Included_com_example_dell_humandetectionndk_OpencvNativeClass
#define _Included_com_example_dell_humandetectionndk_OpencvNativeClass
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/*
* Class:     com_example_dell_mpdetecthumans_OpencvNativeClass
* Method:    convertGray
* Signature: (JJ)I
*/
int toGray(Mat img, Mat& gray);

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL 
Java_com_example_dell_humandetectionndk_OpencvNativeClass_convertGray
(JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong, jlong);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

.cpp File (Android studio says that there is a typo error for "jint" and missing ";"):

```
#include <com_example_dell_humandetectionndk_OpencvNativeClass.h>

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL 
Java_com_example_dell_humandetectionndk_OpencvNativeClass_convertGray
(JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong addrRgba, jlong addrGray){
Mat& mRgb = *(Mat*)addrRgba;
Mat& mGray = *(Mat*)addrGray;

int conv;
jint retVal;
conv = toGray(mRgb, mGray);

retVal = (jint)conv;

return retVal;
}

int toGray(Mat img, Mat& gray){
cvtColor(img, gray, CV_RGBA2GRAY);
if(gray.rows==img.rows && gray.cols==img.cols)
    return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)


#opencv
OPENCVROOT:= C:\OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_example_dell_humandetectionndk_OpencvNativeClass.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
LOCAL_MODULE := MyOpencvLibs


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

My application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-16
```

My app build.gradle

```
sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
}

task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    commandLine "C:/Users/dell/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd",
            'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
            'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
            'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
            'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
```

This is the link of tutorial I am following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oq3oiCfSgbo&t=727s

Comment: Latest Android Studio and Android Gradle Plugins go with support of NDK-Build and CMake. Currently it is not necessary to create gradle tasks for this. Please, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44174164/execution-failed-for-appndkbuild-process-command-ndk-build-cmd-finished-w?rq=1) and [android guides](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html)

Comment: A link to a text file with links to screenshots of text? Just post the error text in the question. If it's too large, use gist/pastebin.

Comment: @Sheikh what are gradle tasks? Does that mean the chunks of codes in my app build.gradle above?

Comment: @Dan Albert ok i edited the post alrdy

Comment: i tried following the stackoverflow answer alrdy, my gradle project sync failed, it says that could not find method ndkBuild() for arguments

Comment: @JonathanSeow, if you will use blocks `externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild { ... } }` in your app build.gradle, then you can avoid creating task **ndkBuild** and make **compileTask** dependant from it in this gradle file.

Comment: Does it? Did you not include that part of the error message? The error message in your question tells us nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

The bulk of the error message is probably directly above what you pasted.  In general, studio's build output looks like:

- Cmake/ndk output here
- final gradle messages here

We'll need the output from the actual build system to diagnose what's up -- can you scroll right above the Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild' bit and see if there's anything that looks like a failure?

Comment: Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :openCVLibrary249:generateDebugSources, :openCVLibrary249:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :openCVLibrary249:mockableAndroidJar, :openCVLibrary249:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :openCVLibrary249:compileDebugSources, :openCVLibrary249:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :openCVLibrary249:compileDebugUnitTestSources]

Comment: that is the rest of the chunk output by the gradle build

Comment: Exit code 2 = windows couldn't find the file you specified.  I'm guessing you have a path error in your manual invocation of ndk build.